# Preimage of linear map

Tags: general-topology

Let $p_1,...,p_m$ be distinct non-zero points of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n \geq 3$.

There exists a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^n   \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(p_1)=1, f(p_2)=2$. To see this complete $p_1,p_2$ to  a basis $p_1,p_2,p'_3,...,p'_m$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists a unique linear $f:\mathbb{R}^n   \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(p_1)=1,f(p_2)=2,f(p'_j)=j$ for $j=3,...,m$.

Let $A=f^{-1}(-\infty,f(p_2))$, $B=f^{-1}(f(p_1),+\infty)$.

> Are they path connected?

They're open beacause $f$ is linear, thus continuous. I also think that $A,B, A\cap B$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus a finite number of points, which is path connected, so this would yield the claim.

However I was unable to justify this passage, do you have any hint?

Comment: What's $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  Preimages of connected sets, this won't help.. What are they apart from this?

Comment: I don't quite get your point.  You want to show that $\mathbb R^n$ is the union of two open and path connected sets where the intersection is path connected as well?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe This thing is part of a proof that $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus a finite number of points is simply connected via Van Kampen theorem

Comment: To answer your comment, yes, plus $A$ and $B$ must be simply connected but this last requirement is not necessary as it follows from the induction hypothesis

Comment: What you want to show is false. You showed something else.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I want to show that the preimages above are path connected: is this false?

Comment: @warm_fish That is not the problem you stated.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Edited

Comment: @warm_fish $p_1,p_2$ are assumed to be linearly independent, right? Otherwise such $f$ does not have to exist. Also what are remaining $p_i$, $i\geq 3$ for?

Comment: @freakish I can assume $p_1,p_2$ are independent, the other points are just distinct points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they path connected?

Yes. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be linear, let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary and let $v,w\in f^{-1}((-\infty, c))$. Now define

$$\alpha:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$$
$$\alpha(t)=tv+(1-t)w$$

and note that

$$f(\alpha(t))=tf(v)+(1-t)f(w)$$

belongs to $(-\infty,c)$ because $f(v)$ and $f(w)$ do and $(-\infty,c)$ is convex. Meaning the image of $\alpha$ is a subset of $f^{-1}((-\infty,c))$. By the arbitrary choice of $v,w$ we conclude that the set is path connected.

The same reasoning works for $(c,\infty)$ and in fact for any convex subset of $\mathbb{R}$. We can make this even stronger:

> **Lemma.** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be linear and $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ convex. Then $f^{-1}(C)$ is convex.

which I leave as an exercise.